# Action posted twice using Handler

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm stuck in some problems with handlers. In particular, I need to stop and resume a callback either when I respectively turn my device lock and unlock, or when OnPause() and OnResume() are called. I put `handler.Post(action)` and `handler.RemoveCallbacks(action)` in OnPause() and in OnResume() but they don't work properly. Actually, when I exit and enter again in my application, It seems that `handler.Post(action)` is called twice because the update of TextView becomes faster than usual. Besides, the same thing happens when I lock or unlock the device. I dont' know how can I solve this issue.
This is my code:

```
 public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    int count = 1;
    TextView text;
    Handler handler;
    myrunnable runnable;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        text = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new myrunnable(text, handler);

    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        handler.Post(runnable.Run);
        base.OnResume();
    }
    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        handler.RemoveCallbacks(runnable.Run);
        base.OnPause();
    }

}
public class myrunnable : Java.Lang.Object, IRunnable
{

    int i;
    TextView text;
    Handler handler;
    public myrunnable() { }
    public myrunnable(TextView text, Handler handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
        this.text = text;
        i = 0;
    }
    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get
        {
            return (IntPtr) 0;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void Run()
    {
        i++;
        text.Text = i.ToString();
        if (i < 100)
            handler.PostDelayed(Run, 1000);
    }
}
```

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im having the same problem. The however, the problem is not the text view it's that onResume is called when the application starts and also when the suspended activity is resumed. Id recommend setting a boolean like canRun that if set false the handler will not post. And if it's true the handler can post and cancel as it pleases. I hope this helps and that im not way off.

Comment: Well, I tried this method and works fine when I need to lock and unlock the screen but not for when I open my application again after OnPause() callback

Comment: @gymnif im not sure i totally undersand. You would like to stop the handler when you lock the screen and resume it when you unlock it?

Comment: Yes, either this or stop handler when I go out from application and enter again in it after a few seconds (when OnPause is called because I choose to use another application)

Comment: So, I want to stop handler when the user is not interacting with the application (because the device is locked or the user open another application)

Comment: I would surround the handler with a statement like if(canRun) is true then the handler will run. If its not true pass over the code. In oncreate and onresume set canRun to true and then in onpause set the variable to false.